# Adding subdirectories to Angular route

Tags: angularjs

I am currently trying to organise my project more neatly, so that I can have a projects folder, for (you guessed it) projects!

In the `app.js` file, I set up my route like this:

```
.when('/contact', {
  templateUrl: 'views/contact.html',
  controller: 'MainCtrl'
})
```

This style of routing works just fine, but when I put a template file in a subfolder, it stops working:

```
.when('projects/dublin-bus', {
  templateUrl: 'views/projects/dublin-bus.html',
  controller: 'MainCtrl'
})
```

The data is just a dummy JSON object, that fills the template in the view:

```
{
  title: 'Dublin Bus',
  url: '#/projects/dublin-bus'
}

<li ng-click="toggleMenu()" ng-repeat="project in projects"><a ng-href="{{project.url}}">{{project.title}}</a></li>
```

This code doesn't produce any errors in the browser, or render incorrect HTML:

[image]

Do I need to declare this route parameter somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that your first example for contact had a `/` at the start, the second problem route did not.  I think I ran into something where I had to have the `/` at the start or it would try to make everything relative, which caused some funky stuff.

```
//     |
//     V
.when('/projects/dublin-bus', {
    templateUrl: 'views/projects/dublin-bus.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl'
})
```